# How to sqlite .dump using Qt

Tags: qt, sqlite

I want to .dump table using Qt like,

sqlite> sqlite3 a.db ".dump" | sqlite3 b.db

I'm using dump for recovery corrupted table or database.
but I want to use dump with Qt.
so I make this code

```
mainDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE" , "first" );
mainDb.setDatabaseName( "main.db" );
mainDb.open();

copyDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE" , "second" );
copyDb.setDatabaseName( "copy.db" );
copyDb.open();

QSqlQuery mainQuery( mainDb );
QSqlQuery subQuery( copyDb );

bool ret = subQuery.exec( "create table contents_list("
                          "id      varchar(128) primary key not null,"
                          "data    varchar(2048) );" );
if( !ret )
{
    qDebug() << subQuery.lastError().text();
}

static const QString QUERYFORMAT( "INSERT INTO CONTENTS_LIST( id, data ) VALUES( '%1' , '%2' )" );

mainQuery.exec( "select * from contents_list" );
QSqlRecord rec = mainQuery.record();
QString id, data;
QString queryString;

while( mainQuery.next() )
{
    id = mainQuery.value( rec.indexOf( "id" ) ).toString();
    data = mainQuery.value( rec.indexOf( "data" ) ).toString(); 
    qDebug() << id << " " << data ;

    queryString = QUERYFORMAT.arg( id, data );
    ret = subQuery.exec( queryString );

    if( !ret )
    {
        qDebug() << subQuery.lastError().text();
    }
}

mainQuery.exec( "delete from contents_list" );

subQuery.exec( "select * from contents_list" );
rec = subQuery.record();

while( subQuery.next() )
{
    id = subQuery.value( rec.indexOf( "id" ) ).toString();
    data = subQuery.value( rec.indexOf( "data" ) ).toString(); 
    qDebug() << id << " " << data ;

    queryString = QUERYFORMAT.arg( id, data );
    ret = mainQuery.exec( queryString );

    if( !ret )
    {
        qDebug() << mainQuery.lastError().text();
    }
}
subQuery.exec( "drop table contents_list" );

mainDb.close();
copyDb.close();
```

this code work normally, but running time is very very long when number of records are over 10000~.
how to decrease running time, or other way to recover corrupted database.

Sorry to my english skill.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `QSqlQuery subQuery( copyDb );` add:

```
mainQuery.exec("BEGIN;");
subQuery.exec("BEGIN;");
```

Before `mainDb.close();` add:

```
mainQuery.exec("COMMIT;");
subQuery.exec("COMMIT;");
```

Comment: just for interest, why commiting the main query before the subquery?

Comment: No particular reason. @kisang did close  `mainDb` first in his original code, so I assumed this is natural to commit it first.